# How to expand existing input formats in forms.datetime field?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to add custom input format for my DateTimeField. Is it possible to add custom input without hardcoding default inputs?

```
class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    updated = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'])
```

I want to add the option that is above but this solution don't look good:

```
class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    updated = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ',
                                                 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                                                 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
                                                 '%Y-%m-%d',
                                                 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                                                 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
                                                 '%m/%d/%Y',
                                                 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
                                                 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
                                                 '%m/%d/%y'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forms.Form gets its `DateTimeField` input formats by calling `formats.get_format_lazy('DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS')`. You could call this and just append your format:

```
from django.utils import formats

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    my_new_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
    updated = forms.DateTimeField(
            input_formats=formats.get_format_lazy(
                'DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS').append(my_new_format)
```

It's not a whole lot prettier, but at least it wouldn't need to be updated if default formats were changed, added, etc. Probably a little bit better.

For a more in-depth look at how DateTimeField works, you can look at `django/forms/fields.py` inside of the django site-packages directory.